# Function to join variable names

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

I am trying to define a function that takes any two strings (possibly predefined as variables, functions, etc.) and join them in one string (which can also be predefined and will keep its definition if so). For example, `join[f,x]` will output `fx` and `join[myfun,ux]` will output `mfunux`. I have tried to use string functions but the inputs need to be quoted. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this:   <StringJoin[ ToString /@ {A, f}]>

Comment: Then you can go back to an executable expression with ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString /@ {B, f}]]

Comment: Since this is a rather weird thing to do, though, I wanted to check why you want to do that. I wonder if there might be another approach to solving the problem you are actually trying to solve that does not require this.

Comment: It should be mentioned that `Symbol` instead of `ToExpression` might be a bit safer towards preventing evaluation of unwanted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic process is to turn the symbols into strings, join them together and then make a symbol again. However, if one of the symbols has a definition this won't work if you don't hold the evaluation of the symbols properly. The following function should work even for symbols that have definitions:

```
SetAttributes[symbolNameJoin, HoldAll];
symbolNameJoin[symbols__Symbol] := Symbol @ Apply[
  StringJoin,
  Map[
   Function[s, ToString[Unevaluated[s]], HoldFirst],
   Hold[symbols]
  ]
];
```

Example of use:

```
x = 1;
symbolNameJoin[x, y, z]
```

> xyz

Comment: This works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a laziyness driven  alternative:

```
SetAttributes[join, HoldAll];
join[sym__Symbol]:= Symbol @ ToString @ HoldForm @ Row @ {sym};

x= 15;
join[x,y,z]
```

> xyz